# GIT based android project on both "Windows and MAC"

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I have created a project on MacBook and is connected with git. For some reasons I am to work on this project from windows based machine and macOS based machine. When I run my project on windows machine it says "git.exe" couldn't be found.

My question is how I would be able to commit changes on this project while connected with same git repository. Is there any solution.

Comment: Ideally this shouldn't be happening.  Any Git install should be able to go the repo and fetch/pull your branch to your local folder.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually it's something to do with the path of "git.exe" but "git.exe" doesn't shown in my project or window file explorer

Answer (score 0):

In terminal of android studio go ahead with git init after installing git desktop on your mac all other commands same as windows or use the version control on android studio.